# Implicit Styles not working on Custom Controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, implicit-style

In my App.xaml I have a few implicit styles

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   ...Blah...
</Style>
```

These styles work for control as long as they are not in a custom control I create.

#### My Control

```
 public class NavigationControl : Control
 {
     public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonStyleProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(NavigationControl));

     public Style ButtonStyle
     {
         get { return (Style)GetValue(ButtonStyleProperty); }
         set { SetValue(ButtonStyleProperty, value); }
     }
 }

 static NavigationControl()
 {
     DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NavigationControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NavigationControl)));
 }

 public NavigationControl()
 {
 }
```

#### My Control Styles and Templates

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NavigationControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationControl}">
   <Button Style="{TemplateBinding ButtonStyle}"
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NavigationButtonTemplate}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationControl}">
     <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NavigationControlTemplate}"/>
     <Setter Property="ButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

Now I would assume that the DefaultButtonStyle's BasedOn would get it from the App level. But it doesnt. The only way to apply the app level style is Override the ButtonStyle by creating a style of type NavigationControl.

Is there a way where the implicit style makes this work?

Answer (score 2):

Setting `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"` will get you WPF's default button style. If you want to use the style defined in your `App.xaml`, you'll need to add a key to that style so you could reference it from your control style:

**App.xaml**

```
<!-- Your style, just with an added x:Key -->
<Style x:Key="myButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   ...
</Style>

<!-- Set the above style as a default style for all buttons -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}">
```

**Your control styles and templates**

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}">
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: The control is in another library. So 'BasedOn="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"' wouldn't work because myButtonStyle is in the App level and my control is in an external library

Comment: In that case, put "myButtonStyle" in a resource dictionary and reference it from your control's library.

Comment: Thats not really the approach I'm going for. What I want to do is have a Platform based style and have my Brands ovverride (but really enhance it). So lets say I have a button size in the Platform and mt Brand stylizes the colors (implicitly). I want both to apply